# How to Resolve Stale Element Reference - Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I cannot seem to apply any of the resolutions to my own situation.

I am scraping a website for certain values, however, the values exist on different profiles on the website. Therefore, I log in, retrieve a value, log out, log back in under a new profile, retrieve a value, log out etc.

The issue is on one of the hover menu items which seem to be generating a stale element reference. I assume this is due to me logging out and back in again? Is this possible to fix or should I rather just start a new WebDriver instance?

Here is my code so far, bear in my that I am very new to Python so forgive any silly errors or assumptions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/SChogle/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("xxxxx")

iframe = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("xxxx")
driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("xxxx")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit_button").click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

Investment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
actions.move_to_element(Investment).perform()

Investment_Summary = (WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a")))).click()

Imp_Prov = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
print(Imp_Prov)

#log-out
log_out = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#btnLogoff"))).click()

#log back in

iframe = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("xxxx")
driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("xxxx")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit_button").click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    try:
        Investment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10,).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
        actions.move_to_element(Investment).perform()
        tries = 3

    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        tries += 1

Investment_Summary1 = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a")))).click()

Imp_Pen = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
print(Imp_Pen)
```

See stacktrace below:

```
174,256,175.68 ZAR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SChogle/PycharmProjects/test1/venv/Web Scraping - BCI.py", line 60, in <module>
    Investment_Summary1 = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a")))).click()
  File "C:\Users\SChogle\PycharmProjects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Those are two lines. Which one is it? post the stacktrace.

Comment: apologies, it is this line: Investment1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [source code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable)

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

The element probably became stale before `if element and element.is_enabled():` after being located in the previous line (`visibility_of_element_located` handles `StaleElementReferenceException`). You can add `ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException]` to the deceleration of `WebDriverWait` to solve this

```
Investment1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException]).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
```

Some more points:

1. There is expected condition `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` to handle frames
2. Python variables should be all lower case
3. You have code repetition, you can use functions instead

   ```
   options = Options()
   options.add_argument("start-maximized")
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
   executable_path=r'C:/Users/SChogle/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
   actions = ActionChains(driver)

   driver.get("xxxxxxx")

   def do_login():
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

       driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("xxxxx")
       driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("xxxxx")
       driver.find_element_by_id("submit_button").click()

       driver.switch_to.default_content()

   def print_content():
       investment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException]).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
       actions.move_to_element(investment).perform()

       investment_summary = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a"))).click()

       imp_prov = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
       print(imp_prov)

   do_login()
   print_content()
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a#btnLogoff").click()

   do_login()
   print_content()
   ```

**Edit:**

According to the stacktrace you added the exception is actually on `actions.move_to_element(Investment1).perform()`. It can be solved by simple loop and retry

```
tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    try:
        investment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
        actions.move_to_element(investment).perform()
        tries = 3
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        tries += 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your pointers, however, when adding the line of code (Investment1) I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Saadiq Did you add the ignore? `Investment1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException]).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))`

Comment: Yup I did. This is what I have: `Investment1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException]).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))`

Comment: I also added the below: `from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException` because I was getting a name not defined error on `StaleElementReferenceException`

Comment: @Saadiq Edited my answer

Comment: I don't know if I am being a complete idiot but I still cannot seem to get it to work. I've updated the code and stacktrace in my question above.

Comment: @Saadiq The element can't be found or not clickable. If you are sure the element exist try using expected condition `visibility_of_element_located`.

Comment: yeah the element cant be found because I think the reference to the element has changed when trying to log in for a second time. But I am sure the element exists, and when checking on the page opened by Selenium, the element in question has all the same details as when it was referenced when logging in the first time

Comment: @Saadiq You lost the reference to the previous element, but you relocated it. Did you try `visibility_of_element_located`? The error message suggest the element is not clickable or couldn't be found. Check if the element exists before executing the failed line on the second time the page is open, not the first time.

Comment: yup I did. Still just timing out. The only way I can get it to work is by using driver.quit() after every log-in

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

1. Check element is present at that location.
2. If yes then you can use javascript click
3. If no then find element again and click.

Comment: how would i go about using javascript click?

Comment: Would this be correct? `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Investment_Summary1`

Comment: yes, if you are not imported javascript executor then try this -'getJsExecutor().executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", "your element here");'